# Spring boot jpa cannot update simple object on postgres database

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a spring boot application with postgres database

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.0.0.jre7</version>
</dependency>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

i made a simple test to create a user, load it from the Db, change one of its properties and save it again

but its not working

here is my UserInterface

```
public interface UserService extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

    public final static String NORMAL_USER = "ROLE_user";

    public User findByEmail(String email);

    public User findByVerificationToken(String token);

}
```

and my junit test

```
@Test
    public void activateUser(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setRegistrationDate(new Date());
        user.setEnabled(false);
        user.setEmail("junit@test.com");
        user.setPassword("12");
        userService.save(user);

        User dbUser = userService.findByEmail("junit@test.com");
        assertFalse(user.isEnabled());
        dbUser.setEnabled(true); 
        userService.save(dbUser); <--- here it dies

        dbUser = null;

        User activatedUser = userService.findByEmail("junit@test.com");
        assertTrue(activatedUser.isEnabled());
    }
```

As mentioned the test creates the user, also the findByEmail works correctly
but when i changed the persisted object and call the save method again i get the following exeption

> 2017-05-03 18:49:20.242 ERROR 3852 --- [           main]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: operator does not
>   exist: character varying = bigint   Hint: No operator matches the
>   given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type
>   casts.   Position: 581 2017-05-03 18:49:20.244  INFO 3852 --- [
>   main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error
>   performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not extract ResultSet 2017-05-03 18:49:20.320  INFO 3852 --- [
>   Thread-5] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@3cc1435c:
>   startup date [Wed May 03 18:49:12 COT 2017]; root of context hierarchy

I can't understand the error since im not comparing anything....

UPDATE - Adding the User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4009074751138066325L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "auth_provider")
    private String authProvider;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "dob")
    private String dob;

    @Column(name = "doc_type")
    private String documentType;

non args constructor and getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a Hibernate/mapping issue. Show us your `User` class. I expect, that Hibernate can't handle the id. In order to save the `User` it has to load it first by Id and that seems to fail.

Comment: I can save. Its not an id issue its an update issue

Comment: No problem, I don't have to help.

Comment: Sorry if i sounded rude, added the User class

Comment: is the id column in the db a varchar or something?

Comment: yes.... varchar. i dropped the table and regenerated it and the id field was created as bigint, i recall that i first started this field as String and later changed it to Long

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: yes, no issues now